# SQL Query to return Remote Access Configuration

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to develop a script that will query a SQL DB and its instances to see if remote access is enabled. I can find lots of information on how to manually do this through the SQL Management Console and commands on how to alter the access, but my search is coming up empty on how to just confirm the current state of the config via sql query. Does anyone know how this would be achieved?

Below commands will allow you to configure the relevant sections to allow or disallow various remote sql connections. I'd like to know how to query the current state of each config itme.

```
exec sp_configure "remote access", <0 or 1> 
exec sp_configure "remote query timeout", <number of seconds> 
exec sp_configure "remote proc trans", <0 or 1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call sp_configure supplying only the setting name in order to query the value:

```
exec sp_configure "remote access" 
exec sp_configure "remote query timeout"
exec sp_configure "remote proc trans"
```

You can also omit both parameters to query the values of all settings.

The results will show you the name of the option, the minimum and maximum values, the current running value (what's actively in use), and the configured value (what will be used once a reconfigure command gets executed).

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

select 
     * 
from 
     master.sys.configurations 
where 
     left(name,6) = 'remote'
order 
     by name

There are a few columns there you might be interested in. But for your questions, I think you want [value_in_use].